# Change TextView on Button Click

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I am working on shopping cart app. In which there is Plus and Minus button for adding the items in cart.

If user clicks on Plus button there is a `TextView` which should change from `0` to `1` or more same things should be done if user click on minus button then value of `TextView` should decrease.

I changed the value but its increase and decrease for more than one row at once.

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
public class ProductListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Product> products;
    private ProductListAdapterListener listener;
    int t;
    int count = 0;
    Context context;
    List<Product> rowItems;
    String[] result;
    ViewHolder holder;

    protected static final String TAG = "ReviewAdapter";
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> mCountHash;

    public ProductListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Product> feedItems,
            ProductListAdapterListener listener) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.products = feedItems;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name, description, price, qty;
        Button btnAddToCart, btnReduce;
        NetworkImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return products.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resources resources = this.context.getResources();
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_product, null);
        final View vii = convertView;

        final Product product = products.get(position);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productName);
        holder.description = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.productDescription);
        holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productQty);

        holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productPrice);
        holder.image = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.productImage);

        // holder.qty=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productQty);
        holder.btnAddToCart = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnAddToCart);
        holder.btnReduce = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnReduce);

        holder.name.setText(product.getName());
        holder.description.setText(product.getDescription());
        holder.price.setText("$" + product.getPrice());
        // user profile pic

        holder.image.setImageUrl("http://flavorbaba.com/adminpanel/images/"
                + product.getImage(), imageLoader);

        holder.btnAddToCart.setTag(position);
        holder.qty.setTag(position);
        holder.btnAddToCart.setTag(holder);
        // holder.btnReduce.setEnabled(false);

        // holder.btnReduce.setVisibility(View.GONE));
        holder.btnAddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count++;

                listener.onAddToCartPressed(product);

                View parentView = (View) vii.getParent();
                // TextView tvqty = ((TextView) parentView
                // .findViewById(R.id.textview1)).getText().toString();
                TextView tvqty = ((TextView) parentView
                        .findViewById(R.id.productQty));
                tvqty.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                // Button btnAddToCart = (Button) v;

                // holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                // notifyDataSetChanged();

                Toast.makeText(activity, String.valueOf(position),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

        holder.btnReduce.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // t = Integer.parseInt(holder.qty.getText().toString());
                // holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(t - 1));

                listener.onReducePressed(product);
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        return convertView;
    }

    public interface ProductListAdapterListener {
        public void onAddToCartPressed(Product product);

        public void onReducePressed(Product product);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you already familiar with recycling system of `ListView`s?

Comment: No i am not familiar can you please guide me for that where i m doing mistake

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works